# Qt curl.exe working in debug/release but not in deploy

Tags: c++, qt, curl

I wanna use curl to send an email. I didn't want to use libcurl so I tried with the .exe file. Here is the code I'm using:

```
QString cmd = "curl smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587 -v --mail-from \"xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com\" --mail-rcpt \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com\" --ssl -u xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com:xxxxxxxxxxxxx-T \"msg.txt\" -k --anyauth & pause";
const char* ccmd = cmd.toStdString().c_str();
system(ccmd);
```

However, when I use it in Qt Creator, either debug or release, it works fine. (I had to add the `& pause` for testing purpose) When deploying it, it just says that it's not recognized as a valid program/batch file. Note that it doesn't say `curl.exe isn't recognized` but `$#@$%@^# isn't recognized` (Some kind of weird writing). I guess it's because it's compiled

Here is how I deploy: Copy the .exe from release >> Qt Console >> `windeployqt --gui .` I also added curl.exe, libcurl.dll and a certificate file. Why isn't it working ? Thanks all.

**EDIT:** Screenshot of the directory
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xuff.png)

Comment: If you are using the `curl` program from your executable's directory, try using as `./curl` or make sure the directory `curl` is in system bin path.

Comment: @rakib_ Doesn't work... I'm on windows... What do you mean by it been in system bin path ? It's in the same folder as the .exe I'll edit the post and add a dir picture

Comment: Take a look at this for how to add custom bin path: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997841(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: @rakib_ still doesnt work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't curl. It's your C++ :) Have a look at this line:

```
 const char* ccmd = cmd.toStdString().c_str();
```

What does it do? `cmd.toStdString()` creates a *temporary* `std::string` object. With `c_str()` you get a pointer to the internals of the `std::string` object. At the end of the line, with `;` to be precise, the `std::string` object gets distroyed and your stored pointer points to nowhere (= is dangling). So accessing this pointer is undefined behavior!

This undefined behavior is guilty why it works on your development machine and not on the deployed machine. The dangling pointer can be seen in the error message you get: $#@$%@^#.

How to solve your problem? Easy, just take a copy of the `std::string` object:

```
const std::string s = cmd.toStdString();
const char* ccmd = s.c_str();
```

Now `ccmd` is valid as long `s` exists. If that's too much lines for you, you can write all in a line

```
system(cmd.toStdString().c_str());
```

The standard guarantees that the temporary object lives until `;` even if it is inside a function call.

Happy coding and cheers!

Comment: Wow it worked! I wouldn't have guessed that myself... Thanks so much!